# JQUERY textarea enter to submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This should be an easy one.

I have a textarea that when I press enter it submits.

I have it resetting the text to "Say something..." however the cursor still blinks.

How can I make it so the user has to click the box again in order to say something else?

```
$("#<? echo $post_unique_post_id; ?>").val('Say something...');
```

Comment: Use `placeholder` attribute. See [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyeuth83/)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to unfocus the textarea using `blur`:

```
$("#<? echo $post_unique_post_id; ?>").val('Say something...').blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to blur the element after submit but please use placeholder for these "hook texts".
So your textarea will have the placeholder attribute.

```
<textarea placeholder="Say something..."></textarea>
```

And then just reset and blur the value of the textarea:

```
$("#<? echo $post_unique_post_id; ?>").val('').blur();
```